# LIKE case-insensitive for not English letters

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like

I want to retrieve rows whose `TITLE` field meets some pattern (*case-insensitive*), and this field contains only *non-English* letters.

I tried this:

```sql
SEARCH * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE UPPER(column_name) LIKE UPPER('%pattern%');
```

However, this doesn't work, may be because the table contains only *non-English* letters.

**UPDATE:**

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM PartnersTable WHERE UPPER(TitleColumn) LIKE UPPER('%pattern%');
```

Where:

`TitleColumn` may contain *"Газпром", "Лукойл", "Йотафон", "Мечта ювелира"*,

`pattern` may contain *"газ", "Ювелир"* etc.

Comment: Can you post some your pattern and some sample data?

Comment: @LeonidSemyonov had you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

I tried it with using  `COLLATE NOCASE` added to the column definition. If you are able to do it, then this is the way to go.

What I tested:

```
CREATE TABLE PartnersTable 
    (`id` , `TitleColumn` COLLATE NOCASE )
;
```

Added same data as in your question:

```
INSERT INTO PartnersTable
    (`id`, `TitleColumn`)
VALUES
 (1, 'Газпром'), (2, 'Лукойл'), (3, 'Йотафон'), (4, 'Мечта ювелира')
;
```

Then tried to select it:

```
select *
from PartnersTable
where TitleColumn like '%Ювелир%'
```

It works.

Demo here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ae8f8/2

Edit:
You can also use it with without `UPPER`. By default `LIKE` is case insensitive.
As per documentation:

> Any other character matches itself or it's lower/upper case equivalent (i.e. case-insensitive matching). (A bug: SQLite only understands upper/lower case for ASCII characters. The LIKE operator is case sensitive for unicode characters that are beyond the ASCII range. For example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ' LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE.)."

Demo here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c9b5d/1

Comment: Sorry for bumping quite old thread, but this does work on sqlfiddle, but does not work in native sqlite

    SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06
    Connected to a transient in-memory database.
    Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
    sqlite> CREATE TABLE PartnersTable (`id` , `TitleColumn` COLLATE NOCASE );
    sqlite> INSERT INTO PartnersTable (`id`, `TitleColumn`) VALUES (1, 'Газпром'), (2, 'Лукойл'), (3, 'Йогафон'), (4, 'Мечта ювелира');
    sqlite> select * from PartnersTable where TitleColumn like '%Га%';
    1|Газпром
    sqlite>

Comment: COLLATE NOCASE working only for ASCII characters

Answer (score 3):

The code is not working because UPPER is working for only ASCII characters([link](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-upper.php#:%7E:text=SQLite%20upper()%20converts%20all,to%20their%20upper%2Dcase%20equivalent.&text=A%20string%20whose%20characters%20are%20to%20be%20converted%20to%20uppercase.)). To solve this I implemented User-Defined function with BindFunction for .NET as below.

```
// for System.Data.SQLite
connection.BindFunction(
    new SQLiteFunctionAttribute("myupper", 1, FunctionType.Scalar),
    (Func<object[], object>)((object[] args) => ((string)((object[])args[1])[0]).ToUpper()),
    null);
        
// for Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
connection.CreateFunction(
    "myupper",
    (string arg) => (arg).ToUpper());

var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText =
@"
    SELECT *
    FROM PartnersTable 
    WHERE MYUPPER(TitleColumn) LIKE MYUPPER('%pattern%')
";
      
command.ExecuteQuery()
```

However it takes longer to execute the query.

Following links might help too

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/user-defined-functions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/compare

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me lot. I used with Javascript custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Redifine Like function (This uses the Sqlite .NET wrapper). Also note VB like uses asterisk wildcard. If you want % replace the string or redefine GLOB instead.

```
     public static void OverrideLikeFunction()
 {
    SQLiteSpace.SQLiteFunction.RegisterFunction(typeof(SQLiteHelper.Ulike));

}

[System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFunction(FuncType=System.Data.SQLite.FunctionType.Scalar, Name="Like")]
;
        Public Class Ulike;
            Inherits System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFunction;
            Public Overrides Function Invoke(args() As object) As object;
            try
            {
                    if (System.Convert.IsDBNull(args(0)) || System.Convert.IsDBNull(args(1)))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return (Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.StringType.StrLike(System.Convert.ToString(args(1)).ToUpperInvariant(), System.Convert.ToString(args(0)).ToUpperInvariant(), Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                                   return null;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data contains only a limited set of international letters, one quick and simple solution is to use [replace()](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) to manually change the case of the international letters.

For example in my case, I am expecting only [a-z], [A-Z] and [åäöÅÄÖ]:

```
// First, use application code to make the search string lowercase.
searchStr = searchStr.toLower(); 

// The SQLite function lower() will not affect ÅÄÖ, so we need 
// to manually replace them with their lowercase versions.
sql = "SELECT * "+
  " FROM table1 "+
  " WHERE "+
  "   replace(replace(replace( lower(name) , 'Å','å'), 'Ä','ä'), 'Ö','ö') LIKE ?";

db.prepare(sql, ["%"+searchStr+"%"]);
```